# Would the word, debris, be singular, plural, or either--conditionally?

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns

My essay speaks of de-orbit "debris" falling to Earth's surface. Like as with the shuttle, it will be strewn in parts across the continent. Follow-on reference to the debris (items) would seem, in the strictest (collective-singular) sense for instance, to require the singular pronoun, it; but the word, they, seems more intuitive...so as not to imply that the debris item(s) all or for the most part would be landing upon one and the same ground location. Your thoughts?

Comment: As always, one needs to be aware that countness of nouns, etic countability of the referent, and grammatical verb-form agreement, are different concepts and sometimes match up in unpredictable ways.

Comment: Thank you, Edwin, for affirming validity of a rationale behind my question. It would seem, therefore, that the dilemma might be best resolved with judicious use of parentheses (the last s is a tweak).